# specify a function as a second parameter with String.prototype.replace() method

Tags: javascript

there is some sections in "Javascript the good parts" i can't understand

```
String.method('deentityify',function(){ 
    var entity = {
        quot: '""',
        lt: '<',
        gt: '>'
    };

    return function(){
        return this.replace( /&([^&;]+);/g  , 
            function(a,b){  <-- this line --->
                var r = entity[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a ; 
            }
        );
    };
}());
```

How this function get its arguments ( a , b )

```
function(a,b){  <-- this line --->
    var r = entity[b];
    return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a ; 
}
```

I've read this section in Mozilla MDN but i can't get it also :((

So please can anyone clear it for me :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression let's you group results with brackets.

So `this.replace( /&([^&;]+);/g` gives you as first argument the matched substring and as the second one the matching inside the brackets.

Look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

In the section `Specifying a string as a parameter` you'll find a detailed explanation.